# Improperly configured error when running django-admin check

Tags: django

I'm relatively new to Django and programming, so I have no idea what caused this error or how to fix it.  I asked another question related to the same error but got no responses so here's a simpler version.

When I run Django-admin check (along with various other commands not including run server) I get the following error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LANGUAGE_CODE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have spent hours googling and nothing I find works (I either get this error or a module not found error).  What can I do?

here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 69, in handle
databases=options['databases'],
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
databases=databases,
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/translation.py", line 60, in check_language_settings_consistent
get_supported_language_variant(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/Users/linnea/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 68, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LANGUAGE_CODE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Edit: I get the module not found error (no module named ) when I set the Django settings module

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Django cannot find your `settings.py` file to run the app. You need to set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to you `settings.py` or if you're using an IDE just add it to your project config.

Comment: When I configure the Django settings module (by running export django_settings_module="<project_name>.settings" is gives me this error:]ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'guide_match'

Comment: what command are you running to run your app? are you using ./manage.py runserver?

Comment: I am using manage.py runserver, yes, but the error doesn't come up when I run the server.  I've been struggling with a related problem for a while that has been leading me in circles with the improperlyconfigured and modulenotfound errors.  Django-admin check is the simplest way I've tried that will give me the error.

Comment: try passing the settings parameter: `django-admin check --settings=settings` where settings should be the name of your settings module